# Best practice to upload files in CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-1.3

Can any one suggest me the best way to write code for uploading a file in CakePHP?

- I need to upload a file and save its name in table.
- If the record saving fails it should not upload the file.
- If the uploading fails then the record should be rollbacked.
- The code should be reusable
- I need to upload the file in `afterSave` callback

Comment: FYI, when you process in PHP, the file upload already has been finished, the file is in a temporary directory. You only have to mode this file to a final location and insert the corresponding row into the DB. (And handle possible failures.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit (2015):** Please see the [Awesome CakePHP](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#files) list for current file plugins (2.x branch [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp/tree/cake2#files))

---

**Edit (2013):** This answer is now a bit dated, so I will just leave a list of all mentioned upload plugins:

- [josegonzalez/upload](https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload)
- [milesj/Uploader](https://github.com/milesj/Uploader)
- [szajbus/uploadpack](https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack)
- [webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin/tree/cakephp2.0) (2.0-branch)
- [bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin](https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin) (2.0-branch)
- [davidpersson/media](http://wiki.github.com/davidpersson/media/) (1.3.x-only)
- [jrbasso/MeioUpload](http://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload) (deprecated)

---

Original answer (from 2010):

> You might consider using the [Media plugin](http://wiki.github.com/davidpersson/media/) that was talked about at the last CakeFest. It is fairly comprehensive, containing features such as creating file variations (ie. thumbnails of images or video), helpers for outputting different types of files, and elements to help create multiple-file upload forms more quickly; and also had a strong focus on security from the outset as I can gather from [the slides](http://www.slideshare.net/real34/the-cakephp-media-plugin). I use it in production and find it works well, plus it seems to be under more [active development](http://github.com/davidpersson/media/commits/master) than other options I have seen if that's anything to go by (eg. [MeioUpload behavior](http://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload/commits/master), [Uploader plugin](http://github.com/milesj/cake-uploader/commits/master), [FileUpload plugin](http://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin/commits/master) and various Bakery/blog posts on the topic).

Comment: Let me shamelessly add [Upload Pack](https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack) to the list

Comment: [Uploader](http://github.com/milesj/cake-uploader/commits/master) and [Upload Pack](https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack) are the top 2 supported CakePHP 2.x libs that I have found after half a day of research and attempts at implementation.

Comment: [Upload Plugin 2.0](https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload) by Jose Diaz-Gonzalez seems like a good choice now.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [File fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::file) section in the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload plugin helpful for my case.