# file upload in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I upload a file using cakephp? is there any framework support for file uploading or should I write my own code for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit (2015):** Please see the [Awesome CakePHP](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#files) list for current file plugins (2.x branch [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp/tree/cake2#files))

---

Original answer:

> CakePHP upload plugins in active development (as of Oct 2010):
>
> - David Persson's [Media Plugin](http://github.com/davidpersson/media#readme) [[slides](http://www.slideshare.net/real34/the-cakephp-media-plugin)]
> - WebTechNick's [CakePHP File Upload Handling Plugin](http://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin#readme) [[blog post](http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/221/CakePHP_File_Upload_Plugin)]
> - Miles Johnson's [Uploader Plugin](http://github.com/milesj/cake-uploader#readme) [[website](http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/uploader-plugin)]
> - Meio Código's [MeioUpload 2.0 Behavior Plugin](http://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload#readme) [[website](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/)]
>
> You could also use the [File class](http://api.cakephp.org/class/file), but I wouldn't reinvent the wheel on this one.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148203/best-practice-to-upload-files-in-cakephp/3162144#3162144

Comment: Thanks @burzum, I've pointed both answers to the maintained list now :)

Answer (score 1):

both is possible

for beginners this is probably the better choice:
http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/uploader-plugin

Answer (score 0):

This component could help you out: http://cakeforge.org/snippet/detail.php?type=snippet&id=36.
Allows uploads to either a database or a directory using FTP. I have some experience with CakePHP, however I have not yet tried this component.

Comment: Cakeforge is no longer in use (superseded by thechaw at the end of 2008, then github at the end of 2009) and only remains live to provide an archive of old code. This particular component was written for CakePHP 1.2, and hasn't been updated since 1.3 became stable.

Answer (score 0):

To just get going try this.

I spent two days searching for a simple way to upload files, I tried lots of methods and couldn't get any to work. This works. It is not secure, it is super basic. For me it is now a springboard. I would use this to understand the processes. Then you can build it up in complexity.

For me I struggled with trying to save `$this->data` - but of cause it is not like the cakePHP blog tutorial. The data you want (all the file info) is buried a couple of levels down in nested arrays so `$this->data['Doc']['files']` is what you are after.

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    `tmp_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    `error` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `size` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

**MODEL**

```
<?php
    class Doc extends AppModel {
    }
?>
```

**VIEW**

```
<h1>Uploads</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>File Name</th><th>Size</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach($files as $file): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $file['Doc']['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($file['Doc']['name'],array('controller' => 'files','action'=>'uploads',$file['Doc']['name']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo number_format($file['Doc']['size']/1023,0).' KB';?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>

<h1>Add a File</h1>
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Doc',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('File');
echo $this->Form->submit('Upload');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
class DocsController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
    public function index()
    {
        // -- list the files -- //
        $this->set('files',$this->Doc->find('all'));
        // -- Check for error -> Upload file to folder -> Add line to database -- //
        if($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            if($this->data['Doc']['File']['error']=='0')
            {   
                if(file_exists('files/uploads/' . $this->data['Doc']['File']['name']))
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('A file called ' .$this->data['Doc']['File']['name']. ' already exists');
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($this->data['Doc']['File']['tmp_name'], 'files/uploads/' . $this->data['Doc']['File']['name']);
                }
                $this->Doc->save($this->data['Doc']['File']);
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```