# How to let users store multiple size images in cakephp environment?

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, file-upload, appcelerator

Im building a mobile app for android & ios using appcelerator. I've build a rest server using cakephp
which returns json.
I would like to know how i could make it possible that users upload a image to a server and the server
resizes this picture to 2 different standard sizes and stores them on the server. This image should be 
accessible trough a json get request along side with other corresponding information. My questions are

How can i autimatically resize pictures that are uplouded by users in to two standard sizes and 
how can i store these images(in folders or DB) so they  are accessible through json alongside their other corresponding infomation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the resizing, just google "php resize image". Store the images in some folder in webroot/img folder and store the file name in the db. You might need to rename the file in case there's another file with the same name. When requested, just give the users the url to your image.

Comment: +1 Sound advice, though the CakePHP [Media plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148203/best-practice-to-upload-files-in-cakephp/3162144#3162144) may save some time.